# Retrieve a field value from inner_hits filtered object throw error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-dsl

In my mapping document, I have a nested object fields as follows

```
"availabilities":{                      
  "type": "nested",                     
  "dynamic": "strict",                      
  "properties": {                     
    "start":                        { "type": "date",   "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"  },
    "end":                          { "type": "date",   "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"  },
    "age":                          { "type": "integer"                         }
  }                     
}
```

I have a long DSL query, in which one of the filters is:

```
{
  "nested": {
    "path": "availabilities",
    "inner_hits" : {
      "size": 1,
      "name": "selected_availabilities"
    },
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "availabilities.start": {
                "gte": "2016-10-08",
                "lte": "2016-10-08"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "availabilities.end": {
                "gte": "2016-10-17",
                "lte": "2016-10-17"
              } 
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to use `inner_hits` to get the selected availabilities object and that returns something like this:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 6000,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "listings_v1",
        "_type": "listing",
        "_id": "228527",
        "_score": 6000,
        "_source": {
          ...my fields....
          ...my fields....
          ...my fields....
          ...my fields....
          ...availabilities has nested objects.....
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "selected_availabilities": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1.4142135,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_type": "listing",
                  "_id": "228527",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "availabilities",
                    "offset": 3
                  },
                  "_score": 1.4142135,
                  "_source": {
                    "start": "2016-10-08",
                    "end": "2016-10-17",
                    "age": 23
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My goal is to use one of the fileds from the selected object in the inner_hits for the calculation of the score. 
Since availabilities object may have multiple object, but there will ALWAYS be only one matching my search criteria. SO this is what I have as my query:

```
function_score": {
  "query": {},
  "score_mode": "sum",
  "boost_mode": "replace"
  "functions": [
    {
      "script_score": {
        "params": {
          "move_in_date_boost": -1350,
          "desired_move_in_date": "2016-11-03"
        },
        "script": "return (inner_hits['selected_availabilities']['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['age']);" 
      }
    },
    {
      ....more functions...
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I use above script, I get the following error:

```
{
  "took": 239,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 4,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "xyz_v1",
        "node": "hgu7no8oo9wwe34wetw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "failed to run inline script [return (inner_hits['selected_availabilities']['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['age']);] using lang [groovy]",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "missing_property_exception",
            "reason": "missing_property_exception: No such property: inner_hits for class: 572da4fc5f5e591a0d7cfec2cde0c998b550b1f4"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

How to get selected_availabilities `age` field in score calculation? Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: have a very similar issue... did you work it out in the end?

Comment: No, eventually I found, it is not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
return (doc['inner_hits']...
```

instead of

```
return (inner_hits...
```

Comment: Tried, but did not work. `doc` cannot access `inner_hits`, as it is outside

Comment: what if you just use `doc['age']`?